# Not Able to Generate SH1 key flutter

Tags: flutter

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_f457swdnpa941st0fnkkmfoi5.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_f457swdnpa941st0fnkkmfoi5$_run_closure2) values: [buil
> d_f457swdnpa941st0fnkkmfoi5$_run_closure2@cad8526]

This is my `build.gradel`
As soon as i run C:\Users\username\StudioProjects\name\android> gradlew signingReport

i run into the above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

In your project root folder run these commands

**For debug**

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

**For release**

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease
```